# Required String parameter 'name' is not present

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, post

I get the error named in the title.

Not sure whats going on

In React Native:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://[my ip address]:8000/add");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({name: this.state.name}));
```

In Spring Boot:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFoos(@RequestParam String name) {
        System.out.println("Received POST request:" + name);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Frontend*

Here you are making a request as a Path variable which is appended to URL.

`http://[my ip address]:8000/add/stateName`.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://[my ip address]:8000/add?name="+ this.state.name);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      xmlhttp.send();
```

*Backend*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFoos(@PathVariable(name="name") String name) {
        System.out.println("Received POST request:" + name);
        return name;
    }
```

*Note: No need to use `@ResponseBody` if you are using `@RestController`*

If you want to send multiple data as a below then ideal way is to create one *DAO/DTO* at the backend side

```
 const booking = { 
   name: this.state.name, 
   location: this.state.location, 
   pax: this.state.pax, 
};
```

Backend

```
public class StateDto{
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String pax;
    //Getter-Setters, AllArgConstructor-SuperConstructor
}
```

Then your controller will be as follow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFoos(@RequestBody StateDto stateDto) {
        System.out.println("Received POST request:" + stateDto.getName());
        return stateDto.getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change your frontend code you can change your backend code from `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody` since you are not adding params but a body in the frontend.

Comment: what if i have more parameters? like name: this.state.name, location: this.state.location, people: this.state.people

Comment: etc i add in this , const booking = {
        name: this.state.name,
        location: this.state.location,
        pax: this.state.pax,
      };

Comment: xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({booking}));

Comment: and I want to save these parameters individually

Comment: This is my result from the above:

Comment: Received POST request:{"name":"Stranger","location":"SG","pax":"1"}

Comment: You could send a complex body object or you change your frontend code to send RequestParameters. See @Jerome`s answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The client is passing 'name' in request body but server is expecting 'name' as a request param.

To pass the 'name' as a request param you can try this :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://[my ip address]:8000/add?name="+ this.state.name);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: this does not work, must i change anything on the spring boot side?

Comment: Use `@RequestParam("name") String name` instead of `@RequestParam String name`